# How can I delete files in directory using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In my system, I am downloading new build everyday in 1 folder and then use it for further causes but after running jenkins job I want to delete files in the folder (not workspace) which will delete specific folders from same directory. This will help me downloading new build every time based on different jenkins job running on same machine.

EG:

I am downloading x.x build and then running jenkins job on machine and then if I want to run other job which requires x.y build, it will just see if SOME build is already there in folder. if it is there, it will not download any kit after that. So, now simplest thing I can do is delete x.x after every jenkins run (post build ) so it will download x.y next time..

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your problem, but there are post build tasks you can usually do that can run shell scripts - so you would just need to write a bash script to do what you need and run it as a post build task.

Answer (score 32):

You can delete the whole folder using this syntax to delete a folder called `bin`:

```
stage('Setup') {
    steps {
        dir ('bin') {
            deleteDir()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution as it's platform agnostic **plus** if the directory doesn't exist, `dir()` will create it before stepping in and deleting it, so it never fails or throw any "Directory doesn't exist" errors!

Comment: Where should this code be placed?  Is any plugin necessary?

Comment: @nicolas-castro , this is to be inserted inside the `Jenkinsfile` (i.e., the pipeline code). For example:


```
pipeline {
    stages {
      // the code is to be inserted here in addition to other stages
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a similar command for deleting file?

Answer (score 3):

If my understanding is right, consider my below assumptions

If your jenkins is running on a Unix server, then you can configure a post build step as suggested by nerdwaller above

1. In the job configuration, in the build step, select the option "execute unix command"
2. In the box for the shell script, you can use `rm -rf <<directoryname>>`

Else, if your jenkins is running on a windows server, then select "execute batch command" from the build step and give the appropriate command like rmdir /Q /S nonemptydir

However, my best approach would be to use a platform independent tool like ant to delete the folders using [Ant Delete Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) and it can be configured similarly like the above two approaches instead selecting "invoke ant" in the build step/ post build step.

This will help you to achieve what you need.