# How to suppress output of 'rm -rf' in Jenkins shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I've a big Jenkins pipeline and when build is run, lot of console output is generated which causes space issue on Jenkins master.

I've following code in Jenkins pipeline with Shell Script, which logs every file being removed. I've lots of log files that cause lot of console output -

```
stage('Logs Cleanup') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh '''rm -rf /home/oracle/test/logs1/* /home/oracle/test/logs2/*'''
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way I can suppress output of that command?

**NOTE:** If same command it run from Terminal, it logs nothing in output.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420241/can-jenkins-hide-its-execute-shell-command-when-running-a-job

Comment: Also I don't know why you need shell to delete files. This can be done more efficiently with Jenkins itself. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26921334/7939871

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete files in directory using jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921334/how-can-i-delete-files-in-directory-using-jenkins)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can jenkins hide its "execute shell" command when running a job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420241/can-jenkins-hide-its-execute-shell-command-when-running-a-job)

Answer (score 1):

For your specific delete using Jenkins only:

```
stage('Logs Cleanup') {
    steps {
        dir ('/home/oracle/test/logs1/') {
            deleteDir()
        }
        dir ('/home/oracle/test/logs2/') {
            deleteDir()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are some comments that solve the problem for you, but no one mentioned that you can control the output of `sh` commands through the command itself.

The `sh` command has some [optional parameters](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) that can be used; one of them is `returnStdout`. In your case, you can suppress stdout like this:

```
stage('Logs Cleanup') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh script: 'rm -rf /home/oracle/test/logs1/* /home/oracle/test/logs2/*', returnStdout: false
                }
            }
        }
```

There are some other useful parameters, for example `returnStatus` will return the status code of the command for use in the pipeline.

Comment: This still returned entire output like `rm -rf /home/oracle/test/logs1/a.txt /home/oracle/test/logs1/b.txt  ...` Even with returnStdout=true.But thanks this is going to help me other cases.